# What is the difference between Self hosted Integration runtime and SSIS integration runtime?

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

Can we use self hosted integration runtime for lifting and shifting SSIS package on prem to ADF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A self hosted IR is used to run pipelines in your own on-prem\virtual environment, and it can not run SSIS packages.
To run SSIS packages, you need an SSIS IR, which runs your SSIS packages on Azure.